# What is the CPLX button on a calculator?

Tags: complex-numbers, calculator

On my cheap "dollar store" scientific calculator, it has a 2nd function button named "CPLX". When you press it, the calculator displays some text similar to the "DEG, RAD, GRAD" that says "CPLX".  When in this mode, you can't add, subtract, multiply, or divide. The equals button doesn't even work.

What is this and how is it used? I'm wondering if maybe it's for complex numbers, seeing that there's also a "a" and a "b" button next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for complex numbers, ones of the form $a+bi$ where $a,b$ are real and $i$ satisfies $i^2 = -1$.

Which calculator is it - you need the manual to learn to manipulate it.

Comment: More correctly $i$ is such that $i^2 = -1$

Comment: @user88595 fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a cheap dollar store calculator. Damin-locky KK-107A, to be exact. I can't find any manual for it online.

Comment: @DantheMan here is a brief summary in Russian if it helps (http://1okey.ru/privat/instruction/instruction/223-2010-07-05-12-43-46.html). They do agree that `CPLX` means a register of complex numbers...

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old question, but I bought a similar calculator and had the same question.  The manual that comes with the calculator is a joke and doesn't actually say *how* to use the a and b buttons.

The calculator that I bought is a 'Jot Scientific Calcultor' from Dollar Tree.

```
The relevant buttons are:
'a' (with second function '->r<theta>')
'b' (with second function '->xy')
'->' (with second function 'CPLX')
```

'a' and 'b' are used to enter the first and second values of a paired number, or to switch between the display for a paired number.

```
For example, to convert from rectangular to polar coordinates:
enter the X coordinate and press 'a'  there will be no apparent change on the screen.
enter the Y coordinate and press 'b'
press '2ndF' and '->r<theta>' and the screen will blank during the calculation
the r value will be displayed.  press 'b' to see the theta value.

To convert from polar to rectangular:
enter the r coordinate and press 'a'
enter the theta coordinate and press 'b'
press '2ndF' and '->xy' and the screen will blank during the calculation
the X value will be displayed.  press 'b' to see the Y value.
```

The 'CPLX' button toggles the system into complex mode.  In complex mode you use the 'a' and 'b' buttons to enter the real and imaginary components of the number, and then the +-*/ functions can be used to operate on the complex values.  None of the other functions work (eg no complex exponentials)

```
The key sequence:
'2ndF' 'CPLX' enters complex mode
'2' 'sqrt' 'a' (puts square root of 2 into the real part of the operand)
'2' 'b' ( puts 2 into the imaginary part of the operand)
'X' (multiplication)  (screen changes to 0, waiting for next operand)
'2' 'a'
'2' 'sqrt' 'b'
'='
displays 0
press 'b' displays 6
```

(1.4142 + 2i) * (2 + 1.4142i) = (0+ 6i)

-Jon

Comment: Thanks! This helped me, I just bought a nearly identical dollar store calculator. They are actually excellent calculators with a huge number of scientific, statistics, and number base conversíon functions. They probably all use the same chip inside.